# File upload change function submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to post files with jQuery, but didnt come anywhere, so i was thinking if i post the form instead, when you select your files, it would have been almost the same. But i got a problem right now, he aint posting the form and i cant figure out what im doing wrong :S

JS:

```
$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() { 
    $("#fileupload").submit();
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="uploadBg">
 <form method="post" action="index.php" id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filesUpload[]" class="filesUpload" multiple="">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-upload"></span> Ladda upp
    </a>
    </form>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
.uploadBg { position:Relative;}
.uploadBg input { width: 94px;height: 24px;position:absolute;top: 10px;z-index:1;opacity: 0;cursor:pointer }
```

Hope any of you guys can tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: could you put a working (well.. not working I guess) example in jsfiddle? If i copy your code it works fine...

Comment: its works here http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8qjj1ze5/ ..

Comment: Aren't you preventing default submit behaviour of the `form`?

Comment: I think it's time to start over, because when i post my non-working fiddle it is working

Comment: I putted the rest of the js code in the fiddle and now its not working http://jsfiddle.net/adqy40yb/